# How to get a markdown text in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question about writing dynamically text with markdown. I'm not sure how to get it so if you will help me It will be wonderful. I know that there are a few plugins when I can get a finished this effect about that but I want to learn something new for me and I don't want to use plugins into this.

So I have a `TextInput` with specific functions when I start writing something in this input, there will show a filtered list with suggesting options (it looks like `Autocomplete` ) and that's it. I would like to make font-weight bolder ( or change color etc. ) when letters from `TextInput` match in the list option suggestion. I tried to do with regex/replace but It's not working correctly.

To illustrate my problem:

Text in input: Al

Text showing in the list:

**Al**abama 
C**al**ifornia 
**Al**aska

[Img from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwRK7.png) 
 [Img with searched element from input in the list children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alL4E.png)

`elements` is an array where I have strings with names of States ( it's just an example ).

```
  const mapData = elements.map((text: string, i: number) => {
    const regexValue = new RegExp(inputValue, 'g');
    const changeColor = <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{inputValue}</Text>;
    const showResult = text.replace(regexValue, changeColor);

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView key={text + i}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.itemListStyle}
          onPress={() => changeText(text, false)}
          disabled={isDisabled}
          activeOpacity={1}>
          <Text
            style={StyleSheet.flatten([
              styles.textItem,
              {textAlign: textAlignList},
              {...listElementsStyles},
            ])}>
            {text}
            {/* showResult */}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  });
```

Do you have any advice on what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

There is a little piece of code about that what I did.

```
  const mapData = elements.map((text: string, i: number) => {
  const hlStyles = {color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20};

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={text + i}
        style={itemListStyle}
        onPress={() => changeText(text, false)}
        disabled={isDisabled}
        activeOpacity={1}>
        <Text
          style={StyleSheet.flatten([
            textItem,
            {textAlign: textAlignList},
            {...listElementsStyles},
          ])}>
          {hlText(text, inputValue, hlStyles)}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  });
```

I created a new function called `hlText`:

```
   export const hlText = (text: string, value: string, ...styles: object) => {
      const index = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase().trim());

      const substringText = (index: number, endIndex: number) => {
        return text.substring(index, endIndex);
      };

      if (index > -1) {
        return [
          <Text key="text1">{substringText(0, index)}</Text>,
          <Text key="text2" style={styles}>
            {substringText(index, index + value.length)}
          </Text>,
          <Text key="text3">{substringText(index + value.length)}</Text>,
        ];
      }
    };
```

and it's working so maybe this post is gonna help someone!

[Working img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5g3q.png)